# Не могу запарсить сайт

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, requests

Не могу спарсить весь текст с нескольких сайтов (на них надо заходить под своим аккаунтом, имя, пароль и доступ к той информации у меня есть)

Ссылки все похожи друг на друга (пример: https://author.today/reader/60079/477128)

Вот мой код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

payload = {
    'inUserName': 'stNIKOLAS',
    'inUserPass': '---------'
}
with open('links.txt', "r") as lin:
    links = lin.read().split('\n')

book = open("book.txt", "a", encoding='utf8')
with requests.Session() as s:
    p = s.post('https://author.today/', data=payload)
    for i in links:
        site = requests.get(i)
        text = BeautifulSoup(site.text, 'html.parser').get_text()
        book.write(text)
```

Мне выдаёт страницу с ошибкой:
[image: Страница с ошибкой]

Comment: Вы знаете что такое [`HTTPBasicAuth`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) ([скрин](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnxY3.png))? Совсем не то, о чём Вы думаете.

Comment: Приведите код текстом, а не картинкой.

Comment: Вам нужно использовать `requests.Session` и в рамках сессии авторизоваться через `POST`-запрос. А уже затем всё в той же сессии запрашивать контент.

Comment: @nomnoms12 об'ясните пожалуста я не понял что ви имеете ввиду. Что мне делать?

Comment: @МиколаВаськевич Вот ответ с enSO, там можно посмотреть пример кода: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17633072/11558617

Comment: @nomnoms12 я сделал то что било там описано, но у меня проблема не отпала. Посмотрите пожалуста на мой код снова ( я его обновил)

Answer (score 0):

Вы передаёте неправильные данные при авторизации. Вам следует использовать `Login` и `Password` для передачи имени пользователя и пароля соответственно.

Также следует посылать форму на `https://author.today/account/login`.

***Пример:***

```py
import requests


LOGIN = '...'
PASSWORD = '...'


payload = {
    'Login': LOGIN,
    'Password': PASSWORD,
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    # Авторизация
    s.post('https://author.today/account/login', data=payload)

    # Получение страницы
    html = s.get('https://author.today/reader/60079/477128').text

print(html)
```

---

**P.S.:**
Посмотреть запрос, который отправляется на сервер при авторизации, можно в инструментах разработчика: `F12 -> Network`

[image: Form Data]